# wordpress menu mobile placement issue

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, wordpress, device-width

I have an issue with my main menu on iPhones and possibly android phones. The menu width is set to 100vw up to 600px. However, on a 320px or 480px screen, when the menu button is clicked and when one enters the page, the page zooms out a little bit every time.

The menu is configured with simple javascript, that looks like this:

```
/**
* navigation.js
*
* Handles toggling the navigation menu for small screens.
*/
( function() {
var nav = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' ), button, menu;
if ( ! nav )
    return;
button = nav.getElementsByTagName( 'h3' )[0];
menu   = nav.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];
if ( ! button )
    return;

// Hide button if menu is missing or empty.
if ( ! menu || ! menu.childNodes.length ) {
    button.style.display = 'none';
    return;
}

button.onclick = function() {
    if ( -1 == menu.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) )
        menu.className = 'nav-menu';

    if ( -1 != button.className.indexOf( 'toggled-on' ) ) {
        button.className = button.className.replace( ' toggled-on', '' );
        menu.className = menu.className.replace( ' toggled-on', '' );
    } else {
        button.className += ' toggled-on';
        menu.className += ' toggled-on';
    }
};
} )();
```

The page works fine on a 320px browser window on a computer, so I guess the problem is device-specific.

I am using the standard Wordpress theme Twentytwelve, and the page can be found here:

http://stilius.se/

I would appriciate any suggestion!

/Stilius